# How to add ".html" to wordpress urls in nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I use nginx and wordpress.  Someone hacked a very popular blogger account and now I try to survive the site. I want to protect old addresses and permalinks. I made a research but could not find because of similar results about the subject. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

How can I add `.html` after my permalinks after my urls. I tried this but I am getting 404 in browser.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
}

location ~ \.html$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location @htmlext {
    #rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html permanent;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does it mean "only in browser"? Do you want to rewrite a request `example.com/some/path/` to `example.com/some/path.html`? Or to rewrite a request `example.com/some/path.html` to `example.com/some/path/`? Do you have static html files on your site now instead of wordpress core?

Comment: actually I solved it. I dont have to add ".html" to urls from nginx. Wordpress handles it in custom permalinks. not sure to erase question or leave it someone can search some kind of question like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using wordpress with nginx, the best way to change  permalinks using wordpress settings. I used this settings to get my old links `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html`

I hope this helps someone.